# Adding ssh authentification for all session

Tags: ssh, kali-linux

I used in the last 6 months Xero linux and Fedora and I added that script into `.bashrc`

```
if [ ! -S ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock ]; then
  eval `ssh-agent`
  ln -sf "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
fi
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
ssh-add -l > /dev/null || ssh-add
```

and it is worked fine. When I opened my terminal, it asked me to enter my passphrase once and that's it but with my new distro, kali linux, I added the script but it does not ask me the passphrase and I need to enter it each time, do you have an idea?
thanks

- Maybe that script is only for arch linux base not for debian, which I have now?

Comment: I'd add `set -x`` above the `if` to see what's happening.

Comment: set -x
if [ ! -S ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock ]; then
  eval `ssh-agent`
  ln -sf "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
fi
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
ssh-add -l > /dev/null || ssh-add

like that?

Comment: Just to correct a conceptual error: what you got now isn't Debian, which is a desktop/server operating system. It's Kali Linux, which is a penetration testing / security toolbox. As per the devs _"it is NOT a recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with Linux or are looking for a general-purpose Linux desktop distribution"_.

Comment: I thought it was a distro like others just some hardened security

Comment: @James78 I edited the question, since all that code in a comment is hard to read.

Comment: @RonJohn Still the same with set -x

Comment: Kali is definitely not just a hardened distro. A lot of things are intentionally broken as they're either irrelevant or pose a security threat for the intended purpose. Check [Should I use Kali Linux?](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/) in Kali documentation for more details.